# I want to make a news app which take data from a wordpress blog

Tags: java, android, wordpress, android-studio, blogs

I just started to make my own app for the first time.

I want to make a news app which take data from my wordpress blog. I designed the app similar to CNN, BBC app for example.  I'd like to make it by my own, not using plugins like apppresser or worona. I use android studio to make the app and just make a listview & row item to list news, but don't know how to take data from wordpress blog.

Could anyone help me? It would be help to introduce me a site about the problem I had. Thanks.

Comment: [Wordpress REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/). Also, no body here will make the app for you. SO is not meant for this...

Comment: @dingo_d Yeah, I know I should practice and study a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you could do is download the raw HTML page you want to get the information from and process it to get what you want to display. Then if you want to keep the app updated with the info, make it repeat the process with a lapse of time (like every 3 minutes for example).

This will work with any kind of page, not just wordpress.

Maybe it will take you a little more time to do this than find an API that does it for you, but since you are new it will be good for you to practice a bit, and, you'll be able to reuse this code incase you stop using wordpress and move to another "plataform".

Comment: It helps me a lot. I need to practice though. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on same project and i use this json api [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/). I gives me json and then i handle it in my project.

You can use volley libaray to handle requests for server. Here is link for volley [tutorial](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. I will try json and ask my friends how to use it. :) Good luck to you!